# How to implement a WebService without the phsyical .ASMX file?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

How do I go about creating a [WebService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.webservice.aspx) without the .ASMX file being present?  (No WSE 3.0 or WCF)

For example my web service looks like,

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class myService : System.Web.Services.WebService {
    //...
```

---

**Note:**
It's well published how to  [create and implement a generic HTTP handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx) through web.config like:

```
// Concept.Handler1Class
namespace Concept {
    public class Handler1Class : IHttpHandler {
    //...
```

and Web.config

```
<handlers>
  <add name="myHandler1" verb="GET" path="myThing.aspx" type="Concept.Handler1Class" />
   <!-- ...
```

No physical *.aspx* file is needed in the above example.

---

I'm looking to do the same with my web services: to have them only exist in the compiled code without a companion front-end file.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about server side piece or purely the client here? From the client perspective what you describe sounds similar to accessing a web service on Java (or other platform). In that case you would need to have a WSDL file describing the service. The URL specified in the WSDL can be overridden in the proxy code to use one of your choosing.

Comment: Server side. I'll update the question.

Comment: I think what you want is Page Methods.  See http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-web-services under Creating and Using Page Methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This codeproject page shows how to do it: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/wsinaclasslibrary.aspx

---

An excerpt for posterity. See link above for full solution.

C# Web Service class

```
namespace WSLibrary {
    public class WSTest : WebService, IHttpHandlerFactory { 
        //...
```

Web.config

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="WSTest.asmx" verb="*" type="WSLibrary.WSTest" validate="false"/>
  <!-- ... -->
</httpHandlers>
```

Comment: And it's that easy. Thanks.  I thought I had tried that already, but likely had a wrong attribute or value - the article you provided led me directly to the fix.

Comment: I had left out the `IHttpHandlerFactory` implementation. That's what caused my problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Ugh--it should be noted this will not work if you need JSON because that is handled by a new `ScriptHandlerFactory` which is marked `internal` so you can't use it :(

Comment: Update: If you need JSON and are still using .NET (pre 4.5), you should encode your output with JSON.net. (the new default JSON formatter used in Framework 4.5)